# Get request to API works fine. Post request return a CSRF token missing but it's there

Tags: django-rest-framework, axios, vuejs3

I have a Django website (with standard views) that I use to register and log in with. Once logged in you can go to a Vue app that gets data from a Django Rest Framework backend. I am using session authentication. Since yesterday whenever I make a POST, PUT or DELETE request I get a 403 error with "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing." but if I look in the headers then the cookie is there because I got it when I logged in. I presume Vue (axios) uses this cookie when it makes requests to the back end API? Why is this not working for me?

Vue main.js:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import axios from "axios";
import "./registerServiceWorker";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000";
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

const pinia = createPinia();

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.use(pinia);
app.mount("#app");
```

Django settings:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "http://localhost:file",
    "http://192.168.1.40:8080",
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://*.127.0.0.1", 
    "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    "http://192.168.1.40:8080",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    "DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer",),
    "DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser",
        "rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS": ["django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend"],
}
```

I get a 403 for all POST, PUT, DELETE requests but here is one view I am trying to make a post request to:

```
class LogoutView(APIView):
 def post(self, request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
   logout(request)
   return Response({"message": "Logged out successfully"},    status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
 else:
  return Response({"message": "No user is authenticated"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and here is the Vue code making the request to the backend:

```
async function logOut() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("/api/v1/users/logout/");
    store.loggedIn = false;
    store.userID = 0;
    localStorage.removeItem("account");
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000";
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Here are the request headers:

```
Accept
    application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
    en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control
    no-cache
Connection
    keep-alive
Content-Length
    0
Cookie
    csrftoken=C4T69wWvlRZ8HeLx80bAFBrHMoRJAUsT; sessionid=lu80tjrcqwqgs14i4qgowob37ejbk90k
Host
    localhost:8000
Origin
    http://localhost:8080
Pragma
    no-cache
Referer
    http://localhost:8080/
Sec-Fetch-Dest
    empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode
    cors
Sec-Fetch-Site
    same-site
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0
```

I presume the cookie in the browser's storage is the one that must be sent to the backend so why is it not being sent?

UPDATE

From what I could figure out this is not working and the header is not included in the headers that are sent to the backend:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
```

How do I force this? or fix it

Comment: Are you logging in from within django or using the Vue app?

Comment: I am logging in within Django

Comment: How do you redirect to your vue app?

Comment: This is all development so the Vue app runs on port localhost:8080 and the Django app runs on localhost:8000 so after logging in on the Django side a user can click on a link and that takes him to the Vue app.

Comment: In your post request from your vue app, can you verify you have set the X-CSRFToken header and its value in the request. Either you have not set it, or the value is incorrect?.
If your request is your logout function (vue) as you have shown, you seem to not be setting the request headers!

Comment: I am using axios to send requests and if you look in the main.js file I presume this setting sets it or am I wrong? axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";

Comment: Ah yes. My bad. It seems to be set automatically.

Comment: and that is where my problem lies because it is obviously not being set for some reason and I cannot figure out why

Comment: csrf is normally used with forms directly from the django template. The quick fix is just to include @csrf_exempt decorator on your django view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely using the newer version of `axios` that requires `withCredentials` AND `withXSRFToken`.

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import axios from "axios";
import "./registerServiceWorker";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;

const pinia = createPinia();

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(router);
app.use(pinia);
app.mount("#app");
```

https://github.com/axios/axios/releases/tag/v1.6.2

> This PR added 'withXSRFToken' option as a replacement for
> old withCredentials behaviour.  **You should now use withXSRFToken along
> with withCredential to get the old behavior**. This functionality is
> considered as a fix.

Comment: I tried your settings and it did not work, so I played around and eventually ended up with the following setting that did work: axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000";
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFToken";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.withXSRFToken = true;
But seeing that you put me on the right path I will accept your answer as the correct one thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your logout function like this:

```
async function logOut() {
  try {
    // Get the CSRF token from the cookie
    const csrfToken = getCookie("csrftoken"); #place actual csrf token here..maybe load from cookie'; 

    // Set the CSRF token in the Axios headers
    axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = csrfToken;

    // Make the logout request
    const response = await axios.post("/api/v1/users/logout/");

    // Reset local state and redirect
    store.loggedIn = false;
    store.userID = 0;
    localStorage.removeItem("account");
    window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000";
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

USe this function to read token from cookie assuming you already have it there..

```
function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
}
```

Comment: Ok but now I have to change every function that makes a request to the backend, where previously it worked fine without me explicitly having to include the header in each request. So my issue is why is axios suddenly not adding the header anymore or is the issue actually on the Django side?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your Django middleware includes `CsrfViewMiddleware`. It looks like you've got it in your settings, but let's double-check it's doing its job.

In your Django settings, ensure your CSRF cookie is set up to be secure for cross-origin requests. Throw in these lines:

```py
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
```

Pop open your browser's dev tools and inspect those cookies. Is the `csrftoken` cookie there? Confirm that it matches the CSRF token in your Django app.

Instead of messing with `xsrfHeaderName`, try the more straightforward approach with:

```js
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

This should magically include the CSRF token from the cookie in your headers.

Make sure your Django app is playing nice with CORS. Confirm that your `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` and `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` match your Front-End and Vue.js app.

Create a dummy endpoint that doesn't need authentication. Let's make sure CSRF is happily working there before tackling the big guns.

Give these tweaks a shot and see if that elusive CSRF token is finally tagging along with your POST requests. If it keeps playing hard to get, your setup might have some specific quirks. As a quick fix, you can use Django's `@csrf_exempt` decorator for specific views but tread lightly for security reasons.

Fingers crossed, and let me know how the CSRF token chase goes!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I have been able to solve it with the following configuration.

In axios request

```
withCredentials: true,
withXSRFToken: true,
xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFTOKEN'
```

In Django settings.py

```
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME='csrftoken'
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False
```